# How to fix SwiftUI tvOS ScrollView jumpy / jittery / flaky / buggy / glitchy behavior?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, scrollview, tvos, behavior

look at this simple example of scroll on tvOS (ver 14.7 18M60):

```
struct TestView: View
{
    var body: some View {
            ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                ForEach(0..<600) { index in
                    Button(action: {}, label: {Text("Button - \(index)")})
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .padding()
                }
            })
    }
}
```

this example will behave badly when scrolling continuously,
the scroll will stop moving and wait for me to finish scrolling on the remote and only a half second after i have finished swipeing on the Apple TV remote then it will update the view and scroll to the requested position,

[See a video with this behavior](https://streamable.com/uueohy)

obviously this is an unwanted behavior, since during the swipe i cannot see where i have reached, therefor i have to stop swipeing, allow the view to refresh and only after i see where the scroll has reached, i can decide wether to keep scrolling or scroll back up (if needed)

it looks like a SwiftUI (try to) optimize performance, but it destroy the whole ATV app experience

i tried fixing it using a ScrollViewReader like this:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct FocusableButton: View
{
    @State var isFocused = false
    let index: Int
    var scrollView: ScrollViewProxy
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Text("Button - \(index)")
        }
            .id(index)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
            .padding()
            .scaleEffect(isFocused ?  1.1 : 1)
            .background(isFocused ?  Color.white : Color.blue)
            .focusable(true, onFocusChange: { focused in
                isFocused = focused
                (focused ? {
                    scrollView.scrollTo(index)
                }() : { /* Lost Focus */ }())
            })
    }
}

struct TestView: View
{
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                ForEach(0..<600) { index in
                    FocusableButton(index: index, scrollView: scrollView)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

[see a video of how it behaves after the fix](https://streamable.com/n34qdu)

but if scroll too fast - the auto - paging - scroll kicks in and crash the app and i get the error (in xcode):

```
Fatal error: ScrollViewProxy may not be accessed during view updates
```

and the runtime issue:

```
Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.
```

[image: the xcode runtime error screenshot]

can anyone help? any idea how to solve it? (the scroll issue or the error)

even if there is a way to bypass the auto paging scroll i would love to see a code example

Comment: Nice title. (voted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**strange fact:** if you surround the `ScrollView` with a `List` (even of 1 dummy item) - the scrolling behaves **correctly**,

so i implemented this test with `List` and it behaves **correctly**:

```
struct TestView: View
{
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40)
        {
            List(0..<600) { index in
                FocusableButton(index: index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

so my current conclusion is that the combination of:

- SwiftUI
- tvOS 14.7
- ScrollView
- ForEach
- Focusable

**wont work!**

---

if i remove the `focusable` and replace it with a `button` the `ScrollView` and `ForEach` also work correctly:

```
struct TestView: View
{
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40)
        {
            List(0..<600) { index in
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("Button - \(index)")
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but all 3 together (ScrollView + ForEach + focusable) behaves badly

Comment: the problem with this is that now i have no way to create a horizontal List (with a focusable object)